# To hide the path and url of videos on my website

Tags: html

just I want to know that I am preparing one website regarding videos. I want to upload on my server or third party's server but I do not want to show the path of the video .. Is it possible..?

Comment: where you want to hide in src or addressbar?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The source of the stream will always be known by the client - the client can't receive from a black hole.

Using Flash you could try to hide it, but only from non-technical users. If you're trying to protect the IP of the source, you might look into a proxy solution.